# Cycles not producing alpha transparency color change

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm very new to Blender Cycles Render and I'm trying to have my character's irises have a white background where the image texture is transparent.

So far, I've come up with this
[image: a]

When displayed in material mode, it seems to be working, but when rendered, it's not.

[image]

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Similarly, for my character's hair, I've done the same thing and the result is somewhat different.

[image]

[image]

Could these problems possibly be related?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I fixed my problem, turns out using a diffuse BSDF rather than a transparent one works